# Refer to views, models and widgets using variables in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am using Pyqt5 and I have a tab widget which has 4 tabs which contain exactly the same layout of widgets - a table view and a few buttons.  The difference is that each tab displays a slightly different view of the data based on one database field which is an integer of 1 to 4.  Below is a snippet of code which sets up the model and view:

```
def setup_folio1(self):
    self.folio1_model = QSqlQueryModel(self)
    self.folio1_model.setQuery("SELECT trans_timestamp, person, charge_code, description, dr, cr, id from "
                               " transactions where folio = 1 and account = '{0}' ORDER BY trans_timestamp".format(myapp.res_id))
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Time stamp")
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "User")
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Charge code")
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Description")
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Debit")
    self.folio1_model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Credit")

    self.folio1_view = self.ui.folio1_1
    self.folio1_view.setModel(self.folio1_model)

    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(0, 120)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(1, 80)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(2, 80)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(3, 395)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(4, 50)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnWidth(5, 50)
    self.folio1_view.setColumnHidden(6, True)
    self.folio1_view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
    self.folio1_view.setDragEnabled(True)

    cr_total = dr_total  = 0
    for i in range(self.folio1_model.rowCount()):
        dr_total = dr_total + self.folio1_model.index(i,4).data()
        cr_total = cr_total + self.folio1_model.index(i,5).data()
    self.ui.folio1_balance.setText(str(dr_total - cr_total))

def setup_folio2(self):
    self.folio2_model = QSqlQueryModel(self)
```

As you can see, I am repeating much of the same code to set up what is essentially different by one digit - whether it is a parameter on the SQL query or more importantly the names of widgets.

As being new to PyQT I haven't been able to figure out how I can refer to these models, views and widgets variably.  I would like to have a method like

```
def setup_folios(self, folio_num=0):
```

and either loop to call the method or loop inside the method.  I would like to vary the number of tabs based on the data but that is phase II.  I have found tabwidgets.count() but I would like to refer to the models, views and widgets in the code using an integer.

Comment: You could create a class `Folio`, which would take a number and create a model and a view, like you do in `setup_folio`. Then you can make several instances, like `self.folio1=Folio(1)`, and you access the models and views with `self.folio1.view`, `self.folio1.model`

Comment: Mel, I am not quite sure I follow you.  I see you point regarding the model/view and it might reduce the amount of code somewhat, but then I still need to set the column width and hide columns as per the code above.

Comment: Sorry Mel, I thought about it some more and now I think I get it.  It would help.  Thanks!  If you want to use your comment with a bit more detail as an answer, I will accept it.